# What is a better way to say "Work Report" without using the word "Report"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am building a web site to allow users to track their work activity. The original purpose was to track your time when "in the field" (out of the office). If a user spends two days in the field on a task, they would submit a form specific to detailing that task. But we want to track in-office time as well. If they are in the office and spend four hours on one in-office activity and four hours on another, they could submit one form for that whole day. The web site will allow managers to generate totals of tasks performed for groups of users.

We want to use the word "Report" to describe the high-level summaries. So, you would go to the "Reports" page to generate a report involving multiple submissions. So, I don't want to use the word "Report" when talking about a SINGLE submission.

I can use any words I want, but I am stuck on finding two words (it could be three) to describe each submission. I have looked on thesaurus.com, but I can't find two words that go well together.

Some ideas:

```
Activity Form
Task Form
Task Submission
Field Activity Submission
```

If someone can suggest a single word that works, that would be fine as well.

Comment: That's called a Timesheet.  The individual entries are... *entries*

Comment: Well, a timesheet is simply hours worked. There are additional fields the users have to enter, like equipment used, location, etc.

Comment: A timesheet as I've used them is much more than hours worked. It contains fields for charge number (or project I'd) activity codes (which can break a project down to a fine level of granularity) and you certainly could add a field in yours for equipment code, location, etc

Comment: Yes, but that's not the purpose of the site. It's not used for accounting for your hours, in that sense. But thanks.

Comment: The main purpose is, "I went to this location for this many days because of this event, and these things went on when I was there". So there would be only one submission for the five people who were present, not one for each person. It's an event tracker, more than a timekeeping system.

Comment: So when you say "original purpose was to ***track your time*** when "in the field" (out of the office) ... But we want to ***track in-office time*** as well. If they are in the office and ***spend four hours*** on one in-office activity and ***four hours*** on another, they could submit one form for that whole day. The web site will allow managers to ***generate totals***..." that's not really what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's not strictly a timesheet, as I have explained. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps an activity/work _summary_?

Comment: Uh… CigarDoug; Jim is broadly correct and you are trying to re-invent a wheel that's already been squared and bent and dented more times than you might imagine.

Doing that in the UK will cost you at least thousands of pounds; with no great stretch of imagination, five figures against stock software costing a few hundred.

All that cost won't begin to explain why *I don't want to use the word "Report" when talking about a* single *submission* is either a reasonable or a viable choice and at the end of the day it's your wheel and you can give it as poor a suspension system as you like.

Comment: No, he is not, sorry. It's not a timesheet, no matter how much you guys want to argue it is. So, unless you are going to make a suggestion, find something else to go comment on.

Answer (score -3):

Activity Analysis may work for you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer has been downvoted (probably) because you don't give any detail. Is this a standard phrase in this context, or something that you made up to fit? What precisely does it mean? How does it differ from the suggestions in the question?